Unable to change display resolution on ubuntu-frame with Raspberry Pi
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 that I've loaded with Ubuntu Core 22 32-bit using the Raspberry Pi Imager. This Pi will be used in a kiosk mode without external keyboard and mouse, as it's a touch display.
I have no problems displaying the snap linking to the web app I want to display, and also no issues with the onscreen keyboard. What I have a problem with is twofold and, I hope, related:

The window doesn't go to the display edge. This is a 1920x1080 display, and when I use snap get ubuntu-frame, the information I get back is as shown below. I'm very new to Linux / Raspberry Pi so I might be missing something, but it appears that the output is meant to be 1920x1080@60.0 by virtue of the line "mode: 1920x1080@60.0".

For any buttons on the top ~1/4 of the visible display, I need to physically touch above the buttons for them to register.


Neither of these two issues are a problem when I'm using Raspberry Pi OS.
Has anyone run into this before and have any advice?
My setup was just these 4 commands to display my webpage in kiosk mode:

snap install ubuntu-frame
snap install wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk
snap set wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk url=<'my URL here'>
snap install ubuntu-frame-osk

The output from snap get ubuntu-frame is:
Key      Value
daemon   true
display  layouts:
'# keys here are layout labels (used for atomically switching between them).
'# The yaml anchor 'the_default' is used to alias the 'default' label

  default:
    cards:
    # a list of cards (currently matched by card-id)

    - card-id: 0
      HDMI-A-1:
        # This output supports the following modes: 1920x1080@60.0, 1920x1080@60.0,
        # 1920x1080@59.9, 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@50.0, 1920x1080@25.0,
        # 1808x1080@63.2, 1680x1050@59.9, 1280x1024@75.0, 1280x1024@60.0, 1440x900@59.9,
        # 1152x864@75.0, 1280x720@60.0, 1280x720@59.9, 1280x720@50.0, 1024x768@75.0,
        # 1024x768@60.0, 800x600@75.0, 800x600@72.2, 800x600@60.3, 720x576@50.0,
        # 720x576@25.0, 720x480@60.0, 720x480@59.9, 720x480@30.0, 720x480@30.0,
        # 640x480@75.0, 640x480@60.0, 640x480@59.9, 720x400@70.1
        #
        # Uncomment the following to enforce the selected configuration.
        # Or amend as desired.
        #
        state: enabled        # {enabled, disabled}, defaults to enabled
        mode: 1920x1080@60.0  # Defaults to preferred mode
        position: [0, 0]      # Defaults to [0, 0]
        orientation: normal   # {normal, left, right, inverted}, defaults to normal
        scale: 1
        group: 0  # Outputs with the same non-zero value are treated as a single display

  side_by_side:
    cards:
    # a list of cards (currently matched by card-id)

    - card-id: 0
      HDMI-A-1:
        # This output supports the following modes: 1920x1080@60.0, 1920x1080@60.0,
        # 1920x1080@59.9, 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@30.0, 1920x1080@50.0, 1920x1080@25.0,
        # 1808x1080@63.2, 1680x1050@59.9, 1280x1024@75.0, 1280x1024@60.0, 1440x900@59.9,
        # 1152x864@75.0, 1280x720@60.0, 1280x720@59.9, 1280x720@50.0, 1024x768@75.0,
        # 1024x768@60.0, 800x600@75.0, 800x600@72.2, 800x600@60.3, 720x576@50.0,
        # 720x576@25.0, 720x480@60.0, 720x480@59.9, 720x480@30.0, 720x480@30.0,
        # 640x480@75.0, 640x480@60.0, 640x480@59.9, 720x400@70.1
        #
        # Uncomment the following to enforce the selected configuration.
        # Or amend as desired.
        #
        state: enabled        # {enabled, disabled}, defaults to enabled
        mode: 1920x1080@60.0  # Defaults to preferred mode
        position: [0, 0]      # Defaults to [0, 0]
        orientation: normal   # {normal, left, right, inverted}, defaults to normal
        scale: 1
        group: 0  # Outputs with the same non-zero value are treated as a single display

